# data-placeholder

Tags: jquery-mobile

Page 146 of the jQuery mobile First look book mentions data-placeholder, but I don't think it's working.  I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Phillip Senn">
<title>jQuery Mobile Matrix</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>slider</h1>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="mySelect">Choose One:</label>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" data-placeholder="true">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>

    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And 'Two' is not the default option.  Shouldn't I be using the selected attribute instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder is for when you have a "Choose one" type item in the list that you don't want to be displayed in the native chooser (the data-placeholder item will display as the native widget's title instead). E.g.:

```
<select>
  <option value="" data-placeholder="true">Choose one:</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

If you want one to be pre-selected, then yes you should use the `selected` attribute.

Comment: Huh.  I'm almost there, except that you didn't include data-placeholder in your example.  And neither did the book, so maybe...I don't know.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work and have pretty much used the same code but I'm getting the placeholder option appearing as just another option. I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.0.a4.1 in conjunction with PhoneGap 1.0.0 if that makes a difference. Do have any experience with using both these technologies? Thanks.